# How to check for NULL values when using the SUM function in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, null, iif

By default, the SUM function in SSRS excludes NULLs.  I want to be able to check for ANY NULL values in the details group and throw an error in the summary group.  In the details view I use this to check for NULLS:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!EquityPrice.Value)) ,"#Error", Fields!EquityPrice.Value*Fields!EquityShares.Value)
```

This works as desired.

When I use this in my summary section, it ignores the NULLS and returns the SUM of the non-null values.  I want to return "#Error" instead:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(SUM(Fields!EquityPrice.Value))) ,"#Error", SUM(Fields!EquityPrice.Value*Fields!EquityShares.Value))
```

I have tried eliminating the SUM in the "IsNothing" expression but to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So just to confirm, if there is at least one `NULL` value in a group, **#Error** should be displayed?

You can use the following for the Summary expression:

```
=IIf(Sum(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!EquityPrice.Value),1,0)) > 0
  , "#Error"
  , Sum(Fields!EquityPrice.Value * Fields!EquityShares.Value))
```

This creates a count of `NULL` values - if that count is greater than zero, return **#Error**.

I made a simple report to test:

[image]

[image]

This uses your expression at the detail level and mine at the summary. Errors for the group with one `NULL` value as required:

[image]